# How to hide/show columns base on slicer in Table Report

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like to ask if there's a workaround to show/hide a column in a table report based on the selected value slicer. I'd like to only show the columns that have values. Please see pic attached.

[image]

Comment: For a Table visual, no there isn't. You can mimic it by using Bookmarks and having multiple Table visuals which show/hide based on the Bookmarks. It is possible with a Matrix visual but this requires a lengthy set-up.